# Why is my __clone() not working as expected?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

So I am using the code below in one of my PHP classes (within a larger library):

```
public function __clone() {
    // recreate this class in its' current state
    $new = new \uri(\uri\generate::string($this->object));
    // give it the same origin
    $new->input = $this->input;
    // now send the new instance back
    return $new;
}
```

In short, I need to recreate the class rather than a traditional clone. However, whenever I use `clone`, it is still returning a regular clone rather than a new instance.

I need to make a new instance because of how reference variables are used within the class.

--

My testing script:

```
$uri1 = new uri('example.com');
$uri2 = clone $uri1;

$uri2->host = 'google.com';

// __toString() returns the URI in its' current state
echo $uri1.PHP_EOL.$uri2;
```

The **expected** output of the test:

```
example.com
google.com
```

The **actual** output of the test:

```
google.com
google.com
```

**My Question:** What am I doing wrong?

I am using PHP 5.5.6

---

For those who need complete context see the link below (lines **145** to **152**). Be warned, there is a lot.

[The library in question](https://gitlab.com/projectcleverweb/php-uri/blob/20417ea5d0a419b54c5243a8b1680310ec2594eb/uri.lib.php)

Comment: What happens if you rename your clone function to `test()` and call it directly? e.g. `$uri2 = $ur1->testClone();`

Comment: hmm... the expected result occurs. While it's nice to know my code works as expected, I am now a little more confused as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the doc

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of
>   the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other
>   variables, will remain references.
>
> void __clone ( void ) Once the cloning is complete, if a __clone()
>   method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone() method
>   will be called, to allow any necessary properties that need to be
>   changed.

So what you need to do is

```
public function __clone() {
    // clone properties that needs cloning (no referancing)
}
```

Comment: wtf? Why should __clone() be called **after** the clone, rather than replacing it (like the other magic methods). Anyways thanks, I think this answers my question =)

Comment: That's PHP :/, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php there are some useful things

Comment: @NickJ It's for convenience...that way you only need to write code to clone properties that specifically need to be deep-cloned, rather than having to write code to clone everything.